# iterated item overriding my model with ngOptions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this

```
<select id="categoryListBox" 
data-ng-model="list" 
data-ng-change="updateCategory(item)"  
data-ng-options="item as item.categoryId[0].name+' : '+item.name for item in list"     
class='form-control' >
    <option value="" style="display:none;"> current category </option>
</select>
```

And whenever `updateCategory` is hit, I `console.log` the parameter, which should be the item I select. The `console.log` reads it as `undefined`.

I also `console.log` the model, `$scope.list`, and it logs as being replaced by the `item` that I select.

What's going on?

Here's the `updateCategory` function

```
 $scope.updateCategory = function(item){
     console.log('updateCategory hit');
     console.log('list is now',$scope.list)
     console.log(item);
 };
```

This comes out as

`updateCategory hit`

`list is now [what item should be]`

`undefined`

The html is wrapped inside of an `ng-hide`, if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-change` is in a different scope than your `ng-options`.  Theoretically, you basically just need to pass in the model, since it will be updated before the `ng-change`:

```
updateCategory(list)
```

But as you see, because it is your model and your ng-options, you then override the list.  So what you need to do, is have your model be something else:

```
<select id="categoryListBox" 
   data-ng-model="selected_item"
   data-ng-change="updateCategory(selected_item)" 
>
```

So - to recap, the model will be set to whatever the selected item is.  If you set the model to be the same thing as the list, the list will become whatever the selected item is when you select.  Probably not what you want.  So set your model to a different variable than your list, and then you can pass in the model to your ng-change function.